# Dynamic landing page headlines (not from keyword)

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm creating a set of display ads in Google that all go to the same landing page. The only thing is that I need a specific headline to display based on whichever ad is clicked on. I'll be differentiating the ads by using URL parameters, however, I don't want to put the full headline text in the URL parameter because the headlines are fairly long.

What I think I need to do is have a coded parameter, such as "/?hl=2", and then use that to dynamically replace the text in the h1 tags with "Headline ABC" or whatever that headline associated with that parameter would be.

Would the best way to do this be through a series of javascript if statements? Or through some sort of php array?

Any suggestions would be appreciated. Unfortunately, I've only been able to find resources about keyword insertion online, not custom headlines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest creating a PHP class and calling a set function that selects the correct text using a switch statement. This is what I have below.

**The Class File** (headerClass.php)

```
<?php
    class hlText{

        public function gethlText($selectedHl){
            switch ($selectedHl) {
                case 1:
                $returnedValue = "The First Header";
                break;
                case 2:
                $returnedValue = "The Second Header";
                break;
                case 3:
                $returnedValue = "The Third Header";
                break;
                default:
                $returnedValue = "The Default Header";
            }
            return $returnedValue;
        }

    }
?>
```

**The PHP File** (whatever.php)

```
<?php 

include 'headerClass.php';

$getHl = $_GET['hl'];

$getHeader = new hlText();

$theHeader = $getHeader->gethlText($getHl);

?>

 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
    <title>Page Title</title>
 </head>
 <body>

    <h1><?php echo $theHeader; ?></h1>

 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: @nikchim did this work for you?

Comment: It seems to be working! Thanks!

Comment: @nikchim Great! Can you mark this as your answer? Thanks.